# Где рассчитывается сумма заказа в последнем шаге оформления заказа?

Tags: opencart

Где именно происходит суммирование всех составляющих в последнем шаге заказа . Мне нужно внести изменения при прибавлении стоимости доставки. Opencart 2.3

Comment: Вы справились с проблемой? Если да, то подскажите как